# Font fallback on Android

Tags: android, fonts, typeface

I'm the developer of an app distributed worldwide.

I would like to use a custom font. Currently it works, but when a character is not supported by the font (for example cyrillic or chinese character), the system automatically use Roboto (or a device specific font).

Is it possible to specify another font to use in case on unsupported characters?

Comment: Old question, but did you find any solution? For my app I just want to show the "question mark".

Comment: @SuperThomasLab Unfortunately no, I didn't

Answer (score 0):

In SDK 29 (Android 10 aka Q) there's `Typeface.CustomFallbackBuilder`.